# How can i open a keyboard in my kivy app?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I created a Python script in Kivy, converted it into an app with buildozer and installed it on my cell phone.
when I click on a text input, the keyboard does not open, how can I change that it opens?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add something like this to your main `.py` file:

```
from kivy.utils import platform
from kivy.core.window import Window
if platform == 'android':
    Window.softinput_mode = 'pan'
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but unfortunately does not work ..
find relatively little on the internet ..
have already tried:
Config.set ("kivy", "keyboard_mode", 'dock')